# Covering Space: definition of $\tilde{X}/Aut(\tilde{X},p)$

Tags: group-theory, quotient-spaces, covering-spaces, quotient-group

If $(\tilde{X},p)$ is a Covering Space of $X$ and $Aut(\tilde{X},p)$ is the group of the Automorphism in $\tilde{X}$, what is the correct definition of $\tilde{X}/Aut(\tilde{X},p)$?

I know that $p:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ is an open map, so we can see $X$ as a quotient space of $\tilde{X}$, and this recall that the automorphism group permutes the points of the set $p^{-1}(x)$ among themselves.

At this point my question is:

$$\tilde{X}/Aut(\tilde{X},p)=[\tilde{x}], \ \tilde{x}\in\tilde{X}$$
$$with \ [\tilde{x}]=\{\varphi(\tilde{x})\mid\varphi\in Aut(\tilde{X},p)\}?$$

And if this definition is correct, is correct to say that $\tilde{X}/Aut(\tilde{X},p)\simeq X$ if and only if $Aut(\tilde{X},p)$ operates transitively on $p^{-1}(x)$ too?

Comment: Yes. You might be interested in the concept of 'normal covering spaces', e.g. in p70 of Hatcher.

Comment: Thank you! I am writing the degree thesis and sometimes I feel like I am stupid ahahah